# Transition for opacity requires a pre-set display block

Tags: jquery, css

I've been fighting with this for a while now. I've declared the following styles.

```
div.contentItem{
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.0s ease;
  display: block; // this line will be discussed below
}

div.contentItemHidden{
  opacity: 0;
}

div.contentItemVisible{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And it works as supposed to **except** for a small, tiny issue. The different divs with contents appear **below** eachother. One can't really see the other divs because of the opacity set to 0 in style contentItemHidden, but they still occupy the space.

Now, i know what you spontaneously want to suggest. *"Use display: none, dummy!"* on the line you're discussing above. But guess what! If i make that change, the opacity transition doesn't have effect at all - nothing appears on the screen.

Now, i know what you spontaneously will say now. *"Put display: block, friend!"* in the contentItemVisible style. But guess what! If i make that change, the opacity transition doesn't have effect at all - the div appears kaboom instead of fading in.

I'm pretty sure that the missing transition has to do with the fact that the element is display: none. So i tried to modify my jQuery code so that right before i swap the classes (contentItemVisible and contentItemHidden), i add block'ification to the display like this.

```
$("#bzzz")
  .css("display", "block")
  .removeClass("contentItemHidden")
  .addClass("contentItemVisible");
```

Still, that has not the desired effect. If i don't remove it later by *.css("display", "none")* i get the weird placement (since the elements take up space, even though they can't be seen). If i do remove it, we get no transition for opacity.

What am i doing wrong? What can i do instead?

A working jsFiddle of what i'm trying to achieve can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/gysvU/4/) (accept that i want to start with invisible DIV's, of course). By changing the style to none for div.contentItem, the transition for opacity is voided.

Comment: This is soooo much easier if you provide a http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I was afraid someone would say that... My hopes were that before that happens, someone **ELSE** would realize what to do. I'll go jsFiddling for a while.

Comment: And my response is, this type of thing is oftentimes solved at this time-consuming step, since it requires a certain rigidness. It's necessary and useful. Don't fear it.

Comment: It's not actually clear what the desired effect is. I'm guessing that you have a number of different content items, and you only want to show one at a time, and you want to fade them in an out. But is the height of the container fixed, or do you want it to track the visible item?

Comment: @Neil Exactly. The height is supposed to follow from the contents. And i wish to display one DIV at a time.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Here you go. It was painful but fair.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten If you don't know the height in advance then I don't think you can do it purely through CSS.

Comment: Oh, and I do hope that you don't use just `-webkit-transition` in finished sites.

Comment: @Neil Haha, no of course not. I'm just assuming that anybody who can provide a valuable answer here is competent enough to reset the extension to his/her browser of choice. Good point though - you never know. I use -webkit because it's right, -moz because it's popular, -o because it's cute and i'm from Scandinavia too and -ms of respect for the rest of my visitors (however, it's a very infected relation there).

Comment: @KonradViltersten The right way of working with relatively stable properties is to list all prefixed versions, and add the unprefixed syntax at the end. (From [Openweb.eu.org](http://openweb.eu.org/articles/vendor-prefixes).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've got a lot of great suggestions here but in the conclusion, i don't believe that the tip i received elsewhere about solving the situation using CSS transition was good. I've used `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` in JS and that made it work. Nevertheless, some valuable info here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
div.contentItem {
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1.0s ease; 
 opacity: 0;
 height: 0;
 width: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

div.contentItemVisible {
 opacity: 1;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}​
```

What I gather from your above post is that you don't really need the `contentItemHidden` class. Just set the `opacity` to **0** by default and toggle it to **1** in your `contentItemVisible` class. Also make the element have `height: 0px` (and throw in the same for padding and margin for good measure) so that it wont occupy any space when its hidden. Of course you can move all those properties to `contentItemHidden` instead and toggle them in `contentItemVisible` if that's the way you want it.

Here's a sample [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LWubb/) for the above.

Comment: Good idea but not working. The problem is that the element is supposed to fade and **then** disappear from the space occupation. I'm starting to believe that CSS transition was a wrong way to go.

Comment: If you want the element to be removed from the DOM then you can't really do that with CSS. You'd have to go the JavaScript way. You can listen for the `webkitTransitionEnd` event (`transitionend` on Firefox) to be notified of when the transition is over and remove the element from DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** use CSS `display: none`, you just have to use `$('#bzzz').show()` and `$('#bzzz').hide()` rather than `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Add/remove class is for the transition to take effect. I tried changing my css("display", "block") for .show() but it had the same effect. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a slideshow. I finally had to use a timer between the adding of the class and the `display: block`.

```
$(item).show();
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $(item).addClass('active');
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is completely possible with a CSS transition. You need to set display:none after the animation is finished and apply display:block before it starts.

CSS:

```
div.contentItem{
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.0s ease;
  display: block; // you don't need this. div is display:block by default
}

div.contentItemHidden{
  opacity: 0;
}

// you don't need this class. div will be opacity:1 by default
div.contentItemVisible{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
// ex. usage
var bzzz = $('#bzzz');
hideItem(bzzz);
showItem(bzzz);

// how we do it
function hideItem(element){
    // listen for fadeout finish
    element.on('webkitTransitionEnd',function(){
        // when it's finished call function to hide the element and remove listener
        removeDisplay(element)
    });
    // start hide css transition
    element.addClass('contentItemHidden');
}

function showItem(element){
    // set to block (item will still have 0 opacity)
    element.css('display', 'block');
    setTimeout(function(){
        element.removeClass('contentItemHidden');
    },0); // setTimeout is used so display:block is executed before starting the transition
}

function removeDisplay(element){
    bzzz.off('webkitTransitionEnd',removeDisplay);
    bzzz.css('display','none');
}
```